# HDFS how to find host name port number on VM

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hortonworks-sandbox

This may seem like a really easy question. But I have a path to my file on hdfs like 
    parentfolder/subfolder/filename.txt 
As I have to give full path to this file with host and port details I need to find out these details. Can you help me how?

Answer (score 1):

Would be something like this depending on config 
      (HDFS config in Ambari: `fs.defaultFS` something like: `hdfs://cluster` with default port `8020`):

```
   hdfs://localhost:8020/parentfolder/subfolder/filename.txt
```